# djangorestframework serializer errors: {u'non_field_errors': [u'No input provided']}

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm using djangorestframework, and someone makes a PUT request to a `.../peoplelist/2/markAsSeen`, passing in just a Person object's id in the URL.  I fetch the Person object (2 in this case) and then simply change the fetched Person object's field `has_been_viewed` to True.  The updated Person object is then to be serialized and returned back to the client.

```
if request.method == 'PUT':
    serializer = PersonSerializer(person,partial=True)#person is a valid object here
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors,)
```

serializer errors is `{u'non_field_errors': [u'No input provided']}`
`serializer.data` looks fine to me

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id',)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're providing a person instance to be updated by the serializer, but no accompanying data to update that instance with.

If you want to deserialize some request data to update that instance with then you're missing the `data` argument, for example:

```
PersonSerializer(person, data=request.DATA, partial=True)
```

However it sounds like the endpoint you want doesn't actually expect to deal with any input data (it's just an empty `PUT` request you're making right?) In which case you don't want/need to be using a serializer at all.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I did not realize that serializer validation is for deserialization onyl.  I had thought that anytime you invoke a serializer (for reading or writing) you needed to validate to make sure that the process went ok.